# Corda Node Explorer with custom cordapps

Tags: corda

Corda ver - 3.1
Node Explorer ver - 3.1

Custom cordapp Node running @ localhost:10006

When i am trying to login to Corda Node explorer using creds for running node @ localhost:10006 , I am seeing following Exception on Node Explorer logs :

**Exception on Node Explorer Logs:**

```
[WARN] 23:04:57,717 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.apply - Cannot find serialization scheme for: [([636F7264610000], RPCClient), UNKNOWN MAGIC] registeredSchemes are: [net.corda.client.rpc.internal.serialization.amqp.AMQPClientSerializationScheme@37f71df5]
[ERROR] 23:04:57,736 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] core.client.run - AMQ214000: Failed to call onMessage
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serialization scheme ([636F7264610000], RPCClient) not supported.
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$schemeFor$1.apply(SerializationScheme.kt:130) ~[corda-serialization-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$schemeFor$1.apply(SerializationScheme.kt:106) ~[corda-serialization-3.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.schemeFor(SerializationScheme.kt:126) ~[corda-serialization-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.access$schemeFor(SerializationScheme.kt:106) ~[corda-serialization-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:136) ~[corda-serialization-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:77) ~[corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:136) ~[corda-serialization-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:106) ~[corda-serialization-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:91) ~[corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:136) ~[corda-serialization-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ServerToClient$Companion.fromClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:370) ~[corda-node-api-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:301) ~[corda-rpc-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.access$artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:97) ~[corda-rpc-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$initSessions$1.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:503) ~[corda-rpc-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$initSessions$1.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:97) ~[corda-rpc-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandlerKt$sam$org_apache_activemq_artemis_api_core_client_MessageHandler$0.onMessage(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt) ~[corda-rpc-3.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1002) ~[artemis-core-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:50) ~[artemis-core-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1125) ~[artemis-core-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) ~[artemis-commons-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) ~[artemis-commons-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) ~[artemis-commons-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
```

**Exception on Corda Node :**

```
[WARN ] 2018-08-09T03:04:57,281Z [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler - Inbound RPC failed {actor_id=user1, actor_owningIdentity=O=CHUBB, L=LV, C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=97f4184a-f4f6-4622-8ab5-791f3fbc570d, invocation_timestamp=2018-08-09T03:04:57.276Z, session_id=06c2ada8-e649-4823-b3d2-ed8055ffdb99, session_timestamp=2018-08-09T03:04:56.121Z}
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serialization scheme not supported.
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.NotSupportedSerializationScheme.doThrow(SerializationScheme.kt:19) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.NotSupportedSerializationScheme.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:23) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:570) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.access$clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:79) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer$createRpcConsumer$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:196) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer$createRpcConsumer$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:79) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServerKt$sam$MessageHandler$5b9bfc45.onMessage(RPCServer.kt) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:997) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:49) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1120) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase$ExecutorTask.run(ProcessorBase.java:53) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
```

Comment: Can you share the custom CorDapp JAR that causes you to see this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Corda Node explorer seems to currently support to have views into a node’s vault and transaction data of Cash. Other customized type states won't work